# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'" after pip install

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

I'm trying to run a python script from the command window, but every time I try to run it I get this error.

```
C:\Users\TJ\Downloads\bovada-hand-history-converter-master\bovada-hand-history-converter-master>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 25, in <module>
    from gui import *
  File "C:\Users\TJ\Downloads\bovada-hand-history-converter-master\bovada-hand-history-converter-master\gui.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this, because when I check `Python36\Lib\site-packages\`, `PyQt5` is right there.  I installed it using `pip` from the command window.  I did the same thing with `pytz` and I'm not having any problems with that.

If anyone thinks they know what's going on, let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: What command did you use to install `PyQt5`?

Comment: check the value of `sys.path`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with versions. PyQt5 is for Python 3.4 (preferably 3.4.4) and it seems you are running Python 3.6.